# Хочу сделать публикацию постов от автора при этом чтобы автор сам передавался в форму через авторизированного пользователя

Tags: python, django

view функция:

```
def post_create(request):
template = 'posts/create_post.html'
form = PostForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('post:index')
    return render(request, template, {'form': form})
context = {
    'form': form

}
return render(request, template, context)
```

models

```
class Post(models.Model):
text = models.TextField()
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
group = models.ForeignKey(
    'Group',
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    related_name='posts',
)
author = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='posts'
)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-pub_date',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.text[:15]
```

forms:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ('text', 'group',)
```

**Как мне передать авторизованного пользователя в заполненную форму?**

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Измените ваше представление:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form = form.save(commit=False)
    form.author = request.user
    form.save()
```

`request.user` хранит в себе текущего пользователя.

Параметр `commit=False` сохраняет форму, но не даёт послать форму в базу данных, что даёт возможность внести в неё изменения вручную. После этого обязательно нужно сохранить форму повторно